# Prometheus avg_over_time, trim begin or end of overlapping data

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Is it possible to trim prometheus query to get a subset of values?

I'm looking into displaying a moving average using `avg_over_time`. My goal is to get the total average count of users connected on different instances of my services over the last 24h.

I already achieved this using a query looking like this: `sum(avg_over_time(users_connected[24h]))`

My only issue is that sometimes new time series start because of the restart of some services leading to old series to overlap with new one for 24h.

If you check the picture ([screenshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4oRb.png)), you can see the sum of average in green, and all the other independant average. When my services reboot, there is an overlap of values for 24h making a big jump in my average.

So what I would like to achieve is somehow discard the first 24h of my new series or the last 24h of my old series to get a nice smooth sum of average, also if there is a better way of doing this I'm all ears :)

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `max`, `min`, `avg`, `median`, `topk` or `quantile` [operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) instead of `sum` in the query.

Comment: @valyala Not quite what I'm looking for unfortunatly,
My use case is to find the average total amount of user connected to my services over the last 24h on many instances. Sometimes thoses services restarts and users get fallback on an other instance / new instance.
Using `min`, `max`.. will give me the average of user per services not the total I guess, or maybe I'm missing something here ?